# Base of semilog in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, logarithm

What is the default logarithmic base of the `semilogx()` and `semilogy()` functions in matplotlib, when not passing any other parameters? Is it base-10, or any other base?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The base of `semilogx` and `semilogy` is 10 unless you set the `basex` or `basey` argument. You can see this in [the source](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py), but I agree it ought to be made clear in the documentation.

Comment: +1 for reference, you could also check it by plotting some simple data, e.g. plt.semilogx([1,10,100,1000,10000], [0,0,0,0,0], 'or')